# Weekend Color cannot be overlap using bootstrap-year-calendar

Tags: javascript

I am using [bootstrap-year-calendar](http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/)

Below code is to collect data from DB:

```
var dataSource = [];
<c:forEach items="${newCalendar}" var="newCalendar">
    var startDate = new Date(${newCalendar.calendarStartYear},${newCalendar.calendarStartMonth -1},${newCalendar.calendarStartDay});
    var endDate = new Date(${newCalendar.calendarEndYear},${newCalendar.calendarEndMonth-1},${newCalendar.calendarEndDay});
    var newData = {
        id: ${newCalendar.calendarId},
        name: '${newCalendar.calendarType}',
        location : '${newCalendar.calendarDesc}',
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        color: '${newCalendar.calendarColor}'
    };
    dataSource.push(newData);
</c:forEach>
```

Below code is to render the calendar, but when I already add an event on the weekends, the color of the weekend cannot be replaced by the color of the data source.

```
$('#calendar').calendar({
    style:'background',
    enableContextMenu: true,
    customDayRenderer: function(element, date) {
        if (date.getDay() === 6 || date.getDay() === 0) {
            $(element).css('background-color', '#e4edec');
            $(element).css('border-radius', '15px');
        } 
    },
    dataSource: dataSource
```

[image]

Comment: Please add complete code or create fiddle which is more better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the library's default behavior that will override any style customization from the one specified in datasource (color).

Simple explanation:
If you override style of the element in `customDayRenderer`, it will be 'overlay' the style you specified in datasource.

Somehow, you can override back the style using `customDataSourceRenderer`. By following these steps:

1. change `style` to 'custom'.
2. Add `customDataSourceRenderer`

Full example like below:

```
...
$('#calendar').calendar({
    style:'custom',
    enableContextMenu: true,
    customDayRenderer: function(element, date) {
        if (date.getDay() === 6 || date.getDay() === 0) {
            $(element).css('background-color', '#e4edec');
            $(element).css('border-radius', '15px');
        } 
    },
    customDataSourceRenderer: function(element, date, event) {
        // This will override the background-color to the event's color
        $(element).css('background-color', event[0].color);
        $(element).css('border-radius', '15px');
    },
    dataSource: dataSource
...
```

**Warning:**
This will only will be solved if you only have 1 event on the day. Any overlapped event on the same day, you will need to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

This code splits the background color of a day in case there are more than one event in that day.

```js
calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
        dataSource: events,
        style:'custom',
        customDataSourceRenderer: function(element, date, event) {
          
          if(event.length==1) {
           $(element).css({
              background: event[0].color 
            });
          } else if (event.length==2) {
            $(element).css({
              background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(50%," + event[0].color + "), color-stop(50%," + event[1].color + "))" 
            });
          } else if (event.length==3) {
            $(element).css({
              background: "linear-gradient(to right, " + event[0].color + " 33%, " + event[1].color + " 33% 66%, " + event[2].color + " 66%)" 
            });
          } else {
            $(element).css({
              background: "-webkit-radial-gradient(blue, yellow, red, green)" 
            });
          }
        }
      }
```